# Does a game have to explicitly support SLI/Crossfire to take advantage of it?

Tags: graphics

This is more of a general curiosity question than a howto question. Just as the title says, do games have to explicitly support SLI/Crossfire to take advantage of multiple graphics cards or are they linked in such a way that you don't need to write extra code?

If explicit support is required, is it common for games to have this support?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's handled at driver level, so even the graphics API doesn't have to know anything about the current hardware state.

Comment: I do think the driver needs to explicitly have a profile for the game to use crossfire/sli.